# Dynamically changing height with prefHeight is not working

Tags: javafx, height, fxml

This is my start method:

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root);
    scene1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Menu");
    primaryStage.show();
```

this is my FXML:

```
<Pane fx:id="loginPane"  maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="- 
 Infinity"minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" 
 prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
 xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">

<children>
<Button fx:id="login" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="37.0" 
 mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clickManager" text="login" />
</children>
 </Pane>
```

And my controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public Button login;
    @FXML
    public Pane loginPane;

    @FXML
    public void clickManager() {
        login.setOpacity(0);
        loginPane.setPrefHeight(700);
        loginPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

Chaning the color is working, but no matter how I play with maxheight and prefheight in fxml and controller It's just not working.Any ideas? What I mean is dinamically changing the height from the controller's method click manager when the button is clicked.

Comment: ` prefHeight="300.0" 
 prefWidth="600.0"` does change height and width. What "not working" ? please explain what is that you want to get, and post [mcve] showing that it does not.

Comment: Dynamically changing the height from controller's clickmanager method when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the height by grabbing the window and setting it from there this is what your `clickManager()` should look like

```
public void clickManager() {
    login.setOpacity(0);
    //loginPane.setPrefHeight(800);
    loginPane.getScene().getWindow().setHeight(700);
    loginPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
}
```

̶I̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶-̶I̶n̶f̶i̶n̶i̶t̶y̶'̶s̶ ̶e̶x̶.̶`̶m̶i̶n̶W̶i̶d̶t̶h̶=̶"̶-̶I̶n̶f̶i̶n̶i̶t̶y̶"̶`̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶f̶x̶m̶l̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶t̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶i̶d̶e̶n̶t̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶m̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶

Also you don't need to set this `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);` twice in your Start method

Comment: Yes, this is working thank you, but as heyza22 has stated I am trying to make changes to the main parent, but when I create a new child I can change its height. Does this mean that the stage is taking the height of the main parent node?

Comment: Yes because you never explicitly set it

Comment: I prefer c0der's answer, since you do not take the size of the window decoration into account which results in scene that is smaller than the parameter you pass to `Stage.setHeight`. Also you may not know the effects on the scene size for all possible cases of modifying the scene...

Comment: @Fabian It sets it to exactly the same height no matter what decoration just tested them both side by side with different decorations what do you mean?

Comment: Note: The `minWidth="-Infinity"` simply means `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`.

Comment: @Slaw Is that different from not having it?

Comment: Having it means the `Pane` _should_ always have a height of at least `prefHeight` (though the `Pane` is the root of the `Scene` which changes some behavior, I believe). Not having it means the `Pane` likely defaults to `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

Have the stage respond (adjust) to the change:

```
    loginPane.setPrefHeight(700);
    loginPane.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
```